# SSRS if statement with date conditions

Tags: reporting-services

I'm new to SSRS and i'm trying to build an expression that would return a "yes" or a "no" if a date falls within the last 12 months.

Something like:

`IIF(date BETWEEN today() && -12 months, "yes", "no")`

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`=IIF(Fields!CreationDate.Value >= DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, -12, Today()) AND Fields!CreationDate.Value <= Today(), "YES", "NO")`